# How can the offset of a segment Off not divisible by the alignment Al in an ELF file?

Tags: c, linux, embedded

```
[Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
[ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 00002a 00  AX  0   0  4
```

As above,the segment begin from 0x34 address, but its Al is 4,so it can't be divided by 2**4.

I mean : 0x34 % 16 != 0.So I want to ask why .text segment's address doesn't begin from Integer times of 16.

Comment: I test it on intel x86.

Comment: A generic what is it question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718388/what-does-an-algn-of-22-and-20-mean/21718432#21718432

Answer (score 1):

The section header struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
   uint32_t   sh_name;
   uint32_t   sh_type;
   uint32_t   sh_flags;
   Elf32_Addr sh_addr;
   Elf32_Off  sh_offset;
   uint32_t   sh_size;
   uint32_t   sh_link;
   uint32_t   sh_info;
   uint32_t   sh_addralign;
   uint32_t   sh_entsize;
} Elf32_Shdr;
```

So what you see under the `Al` column is `sh_addralign`. Let's look at the description of that member from [the elf manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html):

```
sh_addralign
             Some sections have address alignment constraints.  If a
             section holds a doubleword, the system must ensure
             doubleword alignment for the entire section.  That is, the
             value of sh_addr must be congruent to zero, modulo the
             value of sh_addralign.  Only zero and positive integral
             powers of two are allowed.  Values of zero or one mean the
             section has no alignment constraints.
```

**TL;DR**: The alignment constraint shown in the `Al` column is for `Addr` (which is aligned in your case since it's zero), not for `Off`. In other words, it's an alignment constraint for the address where the image is loaded in memory, not for where it's stored in the ELF file.

Comment: Further: sh_offset is the offset in the elf file, not offset in memory.

Comment: Cool,I understant it.You mean that in my case,al is 4,because addr is 0x0?

Comment: Not exactly. `Al` is not 4 _because of_ the value of `Addr` - `Al` is a constraint on `Addr`, not the other way around. And with `Addr == 0` that constraint is met, since `0 % 16 == 0`.

Comment: Also, although the value is constrained to powers of two, it's an actual value not an exponent.  So, 4 means 4, not 16.

Comment: I am a little mess, Do you mean that AL is the value which section used for alignment?so when AL is 4, the section is align with 4 bytes,isn't it?